# CSS: margin a img

Tags: css

I have html like this:

```
    <div id="userBar">
<a href="notifications.php" class="iconGlobe"></A>
<a href="cp.php" class="iconCP"></a>
<a href="cap.php" class="iconCAP"></a>
    </div>
```

.iconGlobe is a icon, same with the redst that looks like this:

```
.iconGlobe{
background: url(../images/icons/globe_16x16.png) no-repeat;
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
border: none;
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Im trying to give margin between the anchor links, like this:

```
#userbar a{
margin-right: 8px; 
}
```

But I doesnt apply the margin. I tried to do it invidually so inside .iconGlobe there was margin-right, and that worked fine. I wish to not apply them invidually.

Comment: I don't think you need the `position: relative;` on .iconGlobe. Which browser are you testing in? Do you have a live example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a problem of case ? in your html you have

`<div id="userBar">` - note the capitol B and in the CSS you have

```
#userbar a{
```

- lowercase b ....

An you need to have block elements for margins -

```
#userBar a{ display:block}
```

Comment: inline-block elements can have margins

Answer (score 3):

you can't give margins to inline-elements. change your code to:

```
#userbar a{
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 8px; 
}
```

but note that older versions of IE might ignore this...

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
#userbar a{
   display: block;
   float: left;
   margin-right: 8px;
}
```

Comment: If the parent div "breaks", try this:+

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. The issue is just with the case mismatch of #useBar and id='usebar'. It works correctly when the case is corrected. See here - http://jsfiddle.net/pGpwb/