Margin or padding for an SVG image in v-app-bar?
This should be a dead-easy question, and maybe isn't specifically vue/vuetify but I'm ramping up and this would help my understanding.
New to vue/vuetify, starting a brand-new front end. I'm using v-app-bar
Here's my app.vue:
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-app-bar :elevation="2">
      <!-- Figure out how to get padding around all sides of the SVG -->
      <v-img src="~/assets/test.svg" position="left" class="ma-2"></v-img>
      <template v-slot:append>
        <v-app-bar-nav-icon></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
      </template>
    </v-app-bar>
  </v-app>
</template>

I'd like to use an SVG as the logo in the navbar header, not text (as the vuetify examples show)
It's working fine except I can't figure out how to get a top+bottom margin around the image.  The class="ma-2" works fine to give me left (and I assume right) margins, but doesn't ever give me top+bottom margin.  Neither did padding.
I expect I'm missing something incredibly obvious... or, as I said I'm brand new to vue/vuetify, is there a better way I should be putting this logo image in the navbar?


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689790/css-margin-a-img

Wrapping it in v-responsive did the trick:
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-app-bar :elevation="2">
      <v-responsive class="pa-2">
        <v-img src="~/assets/test.svg" position="left"></v-img>
      </v-responsive>
      <template v-slot:append>
        <v-app-bar-nav-icon></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
      </template>
    </v-app-bar>
  </v-app>
</template>


Since you are using the svg as the title, have you tried the app-title slot?
<v-app-bar :elevation="2">
  <v-app-bar-title><v-img src="~/assets/test.svg" position="left"></v-img></v-app-bar-title>
  <template v-slot:append>
    <v-app-bar-nav-icon></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
  </template>
</v-app-bar>

